# was/were allocated

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Should "was" or "were" be used in the following?

> One million dollars **was**/**were** allocated for disaster relief.
>
> Millions of dollars **was**/**were** allocated by the government.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: "One million dollars" can be conceptualized as a sum of money, in which case, the singular is used. The plura version, however, is also found.

Comment: What about "millions of dollars"?

Comment: Yes. It should be fine.

Comment: You mean "millions of dollars" can take a singular verb?

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units) that may help you. In this case, *one million dollars* and *millions of dollars* are being used as *mass nouns* and thus can be treated as grammatically singular.

Comment: Is the plural version correct?

Comment: It's "correct" in the sense that you'll hear people saying, but many prescriptivists prefer the singular to avoid the image the the government is doling out a million dollars one at a time.